# no response from manage.py

Tags: python, django, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

When I run any command within ***manage.py***, I get no response from the command line.
In my local machine, it works fine, but on server side it's not responding

```
(env3)root@server /var/www/web/proj3 # python manage.py help
(env3)root@server /var/www/web/proj3 # python manage.py check
(env3)root@server /var/www/web/proj3 # ./manage.py help
(env3)root@server /var/www/web/proj3 # ./manage.py check
(env3)root@server /var/www/web/proj3 # ./manage.py colectstatics
(env3)root@server /var/www/web/proj3 # ./manage.py syncdb
```

some of my configs files

```
(env3)root@server /var/www/web/proj3 # which python
/var/virtualenv/env3/bin/python
```

> ```
> (env3)root@server /var/www/web/proj3 # cat manage.py 
>
> #!/usr/bin/env python
> import os
> import sys
> import site
>
> #Add the site-packages of the chosen virtualenv to work with
> site.addsitedir('/var/virtualenv/env3/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages')
>
> # Add the app's directory to the PYTHONPATH
> sys.path.append('/var/www/web')
> sys.path.append('/var/www/web/proj3')
> sys.path.append('/var/www/web/proj3/proj3')
>
> os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'proj3.settings'
>
> # Activate your virtual env
> activate_env=os.path.expanduser("/var/virtualenv/env3/bin/activate_this.py")
> execfile(activate_env, dict(__file__=activate_env))
>
> import django.core.handlers.wsgi
> application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem somehow to have overridden the contents of manage.py with what should be in wsgi.py.

Replace it with the content from [the original file](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/conf/project_template/manage.py), changing `{{ project.name }}` as appropriate.